# Log message to sumo logic from Android client

Tags: android, sumologic

I've got a requirement to log message from the Android client. Is there any sumo logic API to log message from the Android application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can post your log message/ any message from your Android application to Summo Logic cloud-based log management.

Summo Logic provides Web Services/ REST to perform POST, GET Request.

> You just need to post your data on the request body and mention your
>   Sumo collection endpoint as well as UniqueHTTPCollectorCode.

REST Service/ Web Service : https://[SumoEndpoint]/receiver/v1/http/[UniqueHTTPCollectorCode]

For Instance:
"https://**endpoint1.collection.us2.sumologic.com**/receiver/v1/http/**SanTC12dhaV1oma90Vvb..**."

You can use Retorfit / Volley library for REST Communication .

I have given a below pseudo code which conveys the basic REST Communication in background through Android Async Task.

I strictly recommend to use the above mentioned libraries.

```
public static String performPostRequest(String summoUrl, String payload, 
    Context context) throws IOException {
    URL url = new URL(summoUrl);
    HttpURLConnection uc = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    String line;
    StringBuffer jsonString = new StringBuffer();

    uc.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
    uc.setRequestMethod("POST");
    uc.setDoInput(true);
    uc.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
    uc.connect();
    OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(uc.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8");
    writer.write(payload);
    writer.close();
    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(uc.getInputStream()));
        while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
            jsonString.append(line);
        }
        br.close();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    uc.disconnect();
    return jsonString.toString();
}
```

**Async task**

```
      new AsyncTask<String, String, String>() {

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                try {
                    String response = makePostRequest(""https://endpoint1.collection.us2.sumologic.com/receiver/v1/http/ZaVnC4dhaV1oma90Vvb..."", 
         // Sample JSON Data               "
  {     \"organization": \"organization.name\",
        \"environment": \"environment.name\",
        \"apiProduct": \("apiproduct.name"),
        \"proxyName": \("apiproxy.name"),
        \"appName": \("developer.app.name"),
        \"verb": \("request.verb"),
        \"url": '' + \("client.scheme") + '://' + \("request.header.host") + \("request.uri"),
        \"responseCode": \("message.status.code"),
        \"responseReason": \("message.reason.phrase"),
        \"clientLatency": total_client_time,
        \"targetLatency": total_target_time,
        \"totalLatency": total_request_time
        }", getApplicationContext());
    // Hard coded Success as response from Server, replace with this as per your need
                    return "Success";
                } catch (IOException exception) {
                    exception.printStackTrace();
                    return exception.getMessage();
                }
            }

        }.execute("");
```

For more information, Please refer the documentation from Official Sumo Webpage

https://help.sumologic.com/Send-Data/Sources/02Sources-for-Hosted-Collectors/HTTP-Source/Upload-Data-to-an-HTTP-Source